# Check category before displaying featured image

Tags: post-thumbnails

My single.php shows the featured image:

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail( ) ){
the_post_thumbnail( 'full',array('class'=>'img-responsive') );
}
```

I don't want the featured image displayed if the post is in certain categories.

I have no idea how to write the code, none of the suggestions I found helped me.

Comment: Should be something like "if the post has thumbnail but IS NOT in categories with IDs X and Y, then show the thumbnail".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`has_category()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_category/) will do the trick. You can pass it an ID or slug, or an array of IDs or slugs, and it will return `true` if the post has any of the given categories:

```
// ID
if ( has_category( 1 ) ) {
    the_post_thumbnail( 'full', array( 'class' => 'img-responsive' ) );
}

// Slug
if ( has_category( 'one' ) ) {
    the_post_thumbnail( 'full', array( 'class' => 'img-responsive' ) );
}

// IDs
if ( has_category( [1, 2, 3] ) ) {
    the_post_thumbnail( 'full', array( 'class' => 'img-responsive' ) );
}

// Slugs
if ( has_category( ['one', 'two', 'three'] ) ) {
    the_post_thumbnail( 'full', array( 'class' => 'img-responsive' ) );
}
```

And you can check if the post is not in certain categories by adding `!` to the condition, to indicate 'is not':

```
if ( ! has_category( [1, 2, 3] ) ) {
    the_post_thumbnail( 'full', array( 'class' => 'img-responsive' ) );
}
```

Comment: In understand, but you left out the other "if" - if ( has_post_thumbnail( ). The code should check for that too.

Comment: I'm just showing how to check if the post has a category or not, you can mix or match it with any other conditions you like.

Comment: Thank you so much, it did the trick. Here is my final code: if ( has_post_thumbnail( ) && ! has_category( 240 ))

Comment: No problem. It'd be swell if you could accept the answer.